# social game app

Tags: ios, facebook

I am in the middle of creating a multiplayer game ios app and was considering using facebook's graph to connect players in the same way as the "with Friends".  My question is, what is the best and most efficient way to connect the users stored on my database with each other using the facebook graph?

My initial thought is:
Lets say person A gets the app and registers with facebook, then person B, a friend of person A, registers with the app using facebook.  When person B registers, should I check all of the existing players to see which of them are FB friends with him/her and then connect them in my database?  So in this case, the search through the current users would find person A, and make a connection between person A and person B.  This way, when A wants to challenge a friend to a game, the data is readily available for who he can challenge (in this case, only person B).

I'm sure this isn't the best way, so any ideas are appreciated.  And I am using Django as my backend if that makes any difference in the question.

Comment: please let me know as soon as you get answers on this one! im very interested to see answers here

Comment: I've answered this before, let me find the question and i'll link it here

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetAppUsers using c# opengraph sdk?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7956639/getappusers-using-c-sharp-opengraph-sdk)

Comment: I am also creating one social game and finding efficient way to connect them using fb. Hope to find some great answers.